# How to make the top of FlexibleSpaceBar start at the bottom of SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to make the FlexibleSpaceBar begin at the bottom of the SliverAppBar?

I really like the effects that the FlexibleSpaceBar has but the only way I'm currently able to do this is by adding a some padding to the top, e.g. 50 pixels or so.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AccountScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/account';

  @override
  _AccountScreenState createState() => _AccountScreenState();
}

class _AccountScreenState extends State<AccountScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      drawer: Drawer(),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text('Title'),
            expandedHeight: 200,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Some Text')
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

As you can see the FlexibleSpaceBar begins at the top of the screen behind the SliverAppBar

Comment: I've updated with some example code and an image

Answer (score 0):

I use as this. This makes the top of FlexibleSpaceBar start at the bottom of SilverAppBar.

```
SliverAppBar(
    elevation: 0,
    expandedHeight: 300,  // your wanted height
    flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar()
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply .. I've update my question with some code and an image.